# Creating elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a JS program which works fine if I use the following line of code:

```
    li = $("<li data-role='collapsible' data-iconpos='right' data-inset='false'></li>");
```

But if I change the above line to as follows, it stops working:

```
    li = $('<li/>, {
          data-role: 'collapsible'
          data-iconpos: 'right'
          data-shadow: 'false'
          data-corners: 'false'
    });
```

What is wrong here?

EDIT - Additional code that is failing:

```
    a = $('<a/>', {
        href: fSelectedContent[i].hPageURL,
        click: function () { mSelectCount(fSelectedContent[i].rContentID);},
        html: fSelectedContent[i].rContentName
    });
```

Comment: The first one is valid html while the second is not. It looks like you're missing an end quote after `<li/>`.

Comment: You're missing a single quote after the first argument to `$`: `$('<li />')`

Comment: You accidentally a double quote.

Comment: Thanks folks. It worked like a charm. But my attempt to convert another line failed. Please see above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a JavaScript object literal, a property name must be an identifier or a string.

An identifier cannot include a `-` character, so you have to use strings.

Quote your property names.

---

You also need a comma between each key:value pair.

---

You also need to put a quote to end the string for the `<li/>`.

---

```
li = $('<li/>', {
      "data-role": 'collapsible',
      "data-iconpos": 'right',
      "data-shadow": 'false',
      "data-corners": 'false'
});
```

Comment: and do not quote booleans.

Comment: @rvignacio — They are data attribute values, so they are strings, not booleans.

Comment: @Quentin, the value `false` in JS is obviously a boolean, it isn't necessary to quote it, jQuery's `.attr()` method will put the quotes when adding it to the DOM, and more important, it will put the correct value for attributes like required (e.g.: try `$('<div>', {required: false})`).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would have been to use:

```
$('<li/>').attr({
    "data-role": 'collapsible',
    "data-iconpos": 'right',
    "data-shadow": false,
    "data-corners": false
});
```

But each to their own I guess :)

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent jQuery"?

Comment: I mean that .attr() function is provided as part of jQuery, so why not make use of it?

Comment: jQuery also provides [`$(html, attribtes)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes), why not make use of it? That being said, *I* also prefer the `attr` form and such is not deserving of a downvote. *But*, take care not to implicitly deny the legality of the initial form *and* point out (in words) the problems with the original so that they can be easily recognized.

Comment: Because `$('<li/>, {...})` is also provided as part of jQuery and is smaller?

Comment: Like I say, each to their own

Answer (score 0):

For string literals, if you want to have them roll to the next line you need to use a backslash at the end of the line.

```
var something = 'line 1 \
    line2';
```

In your case though, you're just missing an end-quote after `<li/>`.

```
$('<li/>', {
```

(And, do note Quentin's suggestion above of having proper object literal keys.  You need to quote them if you have `-` in there, or other reserved characters.  +1 Quentin.)